# How can I know what device nodes exist for a USB device?

Tags: linux

I attached GSM Modem on Kubuntu Linux via USB. How will I know the exact path to the device ? It gets detected by the system and when I run lsusb I see the following:

```
rvb@rvb:/dev$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b070 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The device I plugged in is listed as Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Will I know if my device is on /dev/ just by looking at the output above?

Comment: Communications devices are never mounted.

Comment: right.sorry for the not knowing the term

Answer (score 1):

Try running `lshw`, and see if you see anything about a modem or a serial device.  Try running dmesg a couple times directly after connecting the device.  If the USB devices is recognized you may see notices about it setting up something under /dev/ttyS*

Answer (score 1):

For a USB stick you can do:

```
ls -l /sys/dev/block
```

This will give you a list of all block devices that the kernel and udev recognize even before the device is mounted.  The output will include something like:

```
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1......./block/sda/sda1
```

So the new device is /dev/sda1.

Your USB modem is probably a character device so try:

```
ls -l /sys/dev/char
```

Look for a new entry after it is turned on.  For a USB printer I get:

```
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/usb/lp0
```

So the new device is /dev/lp0 and is a character device.